# How can I set a default value on String[] field?

Tags: prisma, prisma2

In my prisma schema I need to set a field to be something like this:

```
  writingDays         String[] @default(["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"])
```

But VSCode tells me:

```
Error parsing attribute "@default": Cannot set a default value on list field.
```

What should I do? I do need some way to set the defaults on this field.

Answer (score 3):

[Docs says](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/working-with-fields/working-with-scalar-lists-arrays) that `Prisma schema does not currently support default values for arrays`

So I'm afraid you would need to handle default values on the application level instead.

```
prisma.entityName.create({
  data: {
    writingDays: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"]
  }
})
```

and etc.

Answer (score 3):

Since prisma 4.0.0 [array support](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#-modifier) is available.

So the original question's code is actually valid code right now:

```
writingDays  String[] @default(["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"])
```

Also, out of the scope, I'd also suggest using an `Enum` for days.